# Html valid input value attributes

Tags: html, standards, w3c

Is the `value` attribute in html subject to the same restrictions as the `id` attribute? Specifically, can I have a numeric `value` attribute.

Comment: Any specific element you are talking about? What version of HTML?

Comment: Checkboxes in this specific case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [list of attributes for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html), it appears that there is no restriction, apart from the `LI` element which requires it to be a number.

---

Update - since checkboxes (which are the element you have indicated in a comment) are `INPUT` elements, they have no special restriction. They can be any valid [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata).

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp), the `value`-attribute of an `input`-tag can be described as of type `text` which pretty much means 'no restrictions', whereas the value of the `id`-attribute [is restricted](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp):

> Naming rules fo the id-attribute:
>
> 1. Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
> 2. Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
> 3. In HTML, all values are case-insensitive

Furthermore, I guess it would not make much sense to restrict the `value`-attribute in any kind because it represents user-input.

---

**//EDIT:**

To avoid w3schools being the only reference (shame on me, but I'm not deleting it in order to keep it as a monument for my rash act), here's a reference to w3.org about the [input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT)-tag and the [data-type of its value-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata). But I'm in trouble now, because both references tell different stories. **According to w3schools**, the data-type of the `value`-attribute is `Text`. **But according to w3.org** (which I sure trust more) the data-type is `CDATA` which comes along with a few general restrictions, e.g.:

> User agents may ignore leading and trailing white space in CDATA
>   attribute values (e.g., "   myval   " may be interpreted as "myval").
>   Authors should not declare attribute values with leading or trailing
>   white space.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata)

And there's also a specific restriction for the `id`-attribute:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: @Oded lol - yeah, I know, it has a bad reputation, but that's the first reference I've found, I'll look for better ones and edit it ;)